What's the purpose of Wormskin Folios?
I collected one while doing a Nexus mission on an infected planet. The wiki says that there are more of these collectibles out there, so I suppose I can find the others in the same method.
But then? Are they a lore element? Or maybe related to a quest?
What am I supposed to do with Wormskin Folios? I have only #1.


Care to edit the question and specify the text and / or the number shown on the Folio?

@Ꮢedacted it's the first one, as you wrote below

Interesting.
The Wormskin Folios were a set of 5 items originally found during Expedition 4: Emergence that provided lore/flavor text about the expedition story (and the Dune worms). The wiki still claims that they can't be found outside that mode.
Yet your message prompted me to search for a bit and I stumbled upon some reddit posts that claim to have got Folio #1 while killing worms on an infested planet. Having just found a paradise AND dissonant AND infested planet (weird combo) I went to check and indeed after some attempt I got a single Folio #1 to drop.
Apparently no player seems to have found a second Folio after the first. In the original expedition you needed to visit the next rendezvous point to make the next folio available, but there aren't rendezvous in the main game, so I don't know how you could trigger the new folio to drop instead. If you want to try, perhaps you could use the portal address of the expedition first rendezvous planet and go check, but I would not expect anything.
The odd part is that getting the folio opens a new page in the discovery/lore section of the menu called "Emergence" (the name of the original Expedition) and automatically adds the text of the first folio and the Writhing Manuscript (another item in the original expedition that has no documented obtain method in the normal game) to the archive. Yet, the remaining folios are not unlocked, almost as there was a way to obtain them.

Ok so if I can't find the remaining 4 this is just... useless?

@pinckerman they would be useless even if you found the other four. The only reason to look for them all would be lore, collection purpose and to fill their page in the archive in your menu. Because yes, the archive has slot for items that can't be obtained outside the specific expedition.

@pinckerman check also this old question I wrote, you will see what I meant

I also found a Memory fragment module, which used to be a milestone reward from Expedition 7: Leviathan. But I can't have its blueprint anymore, right?

@pinckerman The Memory Fragment being normally obtainable as rewards is a known fact. For example, they are guaranteed to drop from unknown traveler graves. The wiki is not updated about the Folio.

Yep, I got it from a grave, but I can't receive the blueprint sadly
